Brother MFC-7340 scanner will not install on 24.04
I ran the Driver Install Tool from here but the scanner does not work.

I found the answer here – thank you Yellow Pasque. 

The problem is that libsane has just been a transitional package that points to libsane1 for several releases of Debian/Ubuntu now. It was removed in Ubuntu 23.10
The easiest way around this is installing the last libsane package to make brscan-skey stop complaining: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/651734016/libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb

The answer is:

Run the Driver Install Tool here first.

Download libsane here.

Install it, e.g.:
sudo gdebi libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb

Remove the CUPS printer, leaving the one automatically installed by Ubuntu.



are you sure that libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb doesn't conflict with libsane1?

I had a look at the entries for libsane and libsane1 on Synaptic and I cannot see any conflicts. Also, when I used apt to install them, it didn't raise any concerns. Happy to run further commands to check this for you; just list them in another comment.

Similar journey: instead, I removed the libsane requirement from brscan-skey so, as you put it above, it stopped complaining. Then install script provided by Brother (linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.4-1). Getting the proper libsane as you did may be the better way to go, but I think I proved that being able to run the script was key to success. Another (untested) way might be to remove the installation of brsane-skey from the script! I didn't need the Scan key functionality, so either would have worked for me. Reference for removing libsane from brscan-skey: https://askubuntu.com/a/1522095/54548
